# select rows with hour and not half hour

Tags: filter, libreoffice, calc

How to extract only rows with hour and not half hour i libreoffice

```
2014/06/15 19:30:00
2014/06/15 20:00:00
2014/06/15 20:30:00
```

=>

```
2014/06/15 20:00:00
```

Comment: So it very much depends on how your time data is represented. Normally any date/time is represented just as a double value, where 1 == 24h. The string representation is just a number format. So if your cells really contain numbers you can check that they are a multiple of 1/24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As moggi pointed out, it depends on the way the time data is presented:

- If your values are valid date/time values for LO Calc, you can just apply the `MINUTE()` function to the complete value to extract the minutes, and compare it with 0. 
  <sub>"Valid date/time" means that, e.g. the date/time value `2014/06/15 19:30:00` is internally represented as double value `40343.8125`. Displaying this as date/time is a matter of formatting. You can check this by manually entering the double value into a unformatted cell and change the formatting to a date value.</sub>
- If your values are text values, you may use a regex to match full-hour time values with something like `.*[:digit:]{2}:00:00$`. You can use this regex in Menu `Data` -> `Filters` -> `Standard Filter` or `Advanced Filter`; don't forget to enable Regular Expressions under the filter's `Options`.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that i could:

1. extract the time part using a =right(D1;8)
2. Do a =IF(MINUTE(D1)<>0,"",1)
3. Sort by the 1's and remove the empty cells.

But, there must be a better and more neat way.

Nicolai